# Weird alignment with checkboxes and their associated text

Tags: css, checkbox, alignment

I've got a aspx website project in Visual Studio but right now I'm running into quite the stupid issue. I've created a checkboxlist that pulls its list items from database. Nothing hard. Works just fine. BUT, the text associated with the checkbox seems to hide itself UNDER the parent check box. Here's a picture so you can see:

Follow this link for the picture. StackOverflow won't let me embed a picture due to not having enough reputition:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCuRw.png

Here's my code associated with the checkboxes:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
        <hgroup class="title">
            <h1>Welcome to the email creation system.</h1>
        </hgroup>
                 To begin, start selecting catagories below.
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="StateCheckList" style="vertical-align: middle; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-align: right" runat="server" DataSourceID="StateListDatabase" DataTextField="State" DataValueField="State" Font-Size="XX-Small" OnSelectedIndexChanged="StateCheckList_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="StateListDatabase" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [State] FROM [MainTable]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
```

All help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Edit:
Here is my Site.CSS information regarding content-wrapper:

```
.content-wrapper {
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 960px;}
```

Here's the paste bin of the entire Site.CSS:
http://pastebin.com/aFsmJ4MB

Comment: The container div is too tight, thus the labels get pushed to the new line. Also, your css is weird, delete that and start over.

Comment: I should of mentioned I am a very fresh beginner. Mind explaining more and or explaining how to fix this?

Comment: Post your CSS so we can see what "content-wrapper" and "title" classes do or are they just identifiers?

Comment: Karl, I added it to the bottom of my post.